# Accessing user name in IDispatchMessageInspector

Tags: wcf, logging, wif

I've implemented custom logging logic for WCF service by using IDispatchMessageInspector.

I'm logging entire SOAP request/response in the database by utilizing both AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply.

I'm using claims-based authentication which works without any issues.

However, when I attempt to access Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name or ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name, I get empty string always (identity is not set, thus name is blank).

Is there a way to access the identity in any way from IDispatchMessageInspector?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to access it in IDispatchMessageInspector?

Answer (score 2):

If your claim-based authentication is working, you could add the user to your claimset.
You can access your ClaimSet in a static way:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimSet> claimSets = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext;`
```

The other possibility is adding a `ServiceAuthorizationManager` to your service, register it in your configuration and access your ClaimSet from this class.

Hope this helps